# How to read a federated user (from the primary domain) in B2C by email

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a B2C directory with local users and internal company users which are federated users (from the primary directory AAD).

In a custom policy I want to read either use type by email.   For local users this is not a problem.

I have not had luck reading against the otherMails claim.  I get a validation error when uploading the policy.   I also have tried saving the user addresses to other claims (employeeId, immutableId) and attempted to read back on those but without luck.

Anyone else done this -- is there a different/better approach?

Comment: @StanleyGong  My full scenario is that I have a custom policy that allows a handful of users the ability to authenticate as themselves but then enter an  email address of another user they need to impersonate (for help desk calls, etc).   The users in the AAD B2C directory are of two types -- 1) local users (third party partners) and 2) federated users from our internal, corporate AAD.    Impersonating  the local users is working.  The solution is based off of sample https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/impersonation  .

Comment: @StanleyGong What I do not have working is impersonating the federated users.  What I'd like to do is read the user based on otherMails but when I attempt to upload a custom policy with a step to Read the user from the B2C directory by the otherMails claim I get a validation message '.Input Claim 'otherMails' is not supported in Azure Active Directory Provider technical profile 'SelfAsserted-TargetEmailExchangeFederated' of policy 'B2C_1A_Impersonation'.

Comment: Note, 'otherMails' is defined in the base policy so it seems it is just not supported to 'Read' on.  I get this same error message if I try the  mailNickname attribute.       I can successfully upload and run  the policy searching  by other attributes such as employeeId, or immutableId however these have other limitations  (size, uniqueness)   that don't make them viable to store email addresses in.

Comment: Is there a way to read a user profile by otherMails?

If not, is there another field I could use? (I tried adding an extended attribute, policy would run but the account would not be found).

Short of either of those, is there a way to read the account from our corporate AAD by email from the custom policy? (calling the graph api, etc).